# error in convert binary value in txt file to image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I have file have some value like this "01100000,10101000,01101000,01110000,10101100,01110000,01101000,10101 " this is the value of JPEG image (120*160)and I need to convert this file to image, I'm trying with this code but I have this error!

> pixels[x,y] = diff(i2) #Creates a black image. What do? TypeError:
> color must be int or tuple

```
with open("C://Users//kk//Desktop//rbb8bin.txt") as file:
    vdiv = [line.strip() for line in file]
print(vdiv)

def diff(inp):
    if inp == '1':
        return (0,0,0)
    if inp == '0':
        return (255,255,255)
    else:
        pass
img = Image.new( 'RGB', (8,len(vdiv)), "white")
pixels = img.load()

for x in range(img.size[0]):
    for y in range(img.size[1]):
        for i in vdiv:
            for i2 in i:
                pixels[x,y] = diff(i2) #Creates a black image. What do?

img.show()
```

Comment: Your best bet is to share the image (Dropbox or Google Drive or similar) and everything you know about it, e.g. height, width, greyscale/colour, 8/16 bit.

Comment: this is JPEJ image, (120*160)

Comment: No, that is not JPEG. JPEG starts with `ff d8 ff`.

Comment: No, I printed the value in binary not in hex

Comment: And the binary you have shown amounts to `60 a8 68 70` which is not `ff d8 ff`. Please share your file so we can actually assist you.

Comment: ok I will share.

Comment: I sheared file data and delet the code because the number of line very long!

Comment: I am rolling back your edit because that isn't how StackOverflow works - it is about the code. I will answer your question in a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to differentiate between ASCII text and binary files. Your file is stored in a very ugly, inefficient way. Here's one (equally ugly) way of making it back into a JPEG:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv

# Read text file as CSV into list
with open('data') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # Discard height and width, i.e. first two values
    data = list(reader)[0][2:]

# Open binary output file, convert each string to bytes and write
with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as out:
    for v in data:
        b = int(v,2).to_bytes(1,byteorder='big')
        out.write(b)
```

[image]